# which selenium jar is compatible with Mozilla Firefox version 59.0.2 (32-bit)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Previously I was using Selenium version 2.53 with Firefox version  40.0.1. But now Firefox is updated and I am trying to do with updated version.

So, respond me about "which Selenium JAR is compatible with Mozilla Firefox version 59.0.2 (32-bit)"

Comment: what's the issue with the current version of selenium?

Comment: in my organization, they have updated browsers and now they can't downgrade. that's why need to work with updated one.

Answer (score 0):

As per best practices you must adopt any one from the below mentioned configurations:

[image: chart]